# python csv TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, csv, syntax, syntax-error

Hi Im trying to compare two csv files and get the difference. However i get the above mentioned error. Could someone kindly give a helping hand. Thanks

```
import csv

f = open('ted.csv','r')
psv_f = csv.reader(f)
attendees1 = []
for row in psv_f:
attendees1.append(row)

f.close

f = open('ted2.csv','r')
psv_f = csv.reader(f)
attendees2 = []
for row in psv_f:
    attendees2.append(row)


f.close

attendees11 = set(attendees1)
attendees12 = set(attendees2)

print (attendees12.difference(attendees11))
```

Comment: could you provide the full trace back

Comment: Hmm dont quite get what you would need regarding full trace back

Comment: To see which line causes the probem

Comment: Ah thanks its on the line with the attendees11 = set(attendees1) Thanks

Comment: In general, a full traceback is worthwhile because they're usually concise anyway and have multiple pieces of useful information for the error.

Comment: Okay get that . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate csv reader you get lists, so when you do

```
for row in psv_f:
    attendees2.append(row)
```

Row is actually a list instance. so attendees1 / attendees2 is a **list of lists.**

When you convert it to set() it need to make sure no item appear more than once, and set() relay on hash function of the items in the list. so you are getting error because when you convert to set() it try to hash a list but list is not hashable.

You will get the same exception if you do something like this:

```
set([1, 2, [1,2] ])
```

More in sets: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 1):

Happened on the line

```
attendees11 = set(attendees1)
```

didn't it? You are trying to make a set from a list of lists but it is impossible because set may only contain hashable types, which list is not. You can convert the lists to tuples.

```
attendees1.append(tuple(row))
```

Comment: @MichalK if it helped you solve your problem don't hesitate to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Causes you created list of list:

```
attendees1.append(row)
```

Like wise:

```
attendees2.append(row)
```

Then when you do :

```
attendees11 = set(attendees1)
```

The error will be thrown

What you should do is :

```
attendees2.append(tuple(row))
```